Specify priors for only one parameter in INLA
I have the model:
I1 <- inla(n ~ median + weight + length,
           control.predictor = list(compute = TRUE),  
           quantiles = c(0.025, 0.975),
           control.compute=list(dic = TRUE, waic = TRUE, cpo=TRUE, return.marginals.predictor=TRUE),
           family = "poisson", 
           data = df)

and I want to specify priors only for length (I believe that it should have negative coefficient).
How can I do it?

If length is your only parameter, how do you want to handle median and weight? Are they constants?  As for forcing length to have a negative coefficient, the simplest way is probably to transform your data so that, say, negative_length <- - length and then use negative_length in your model with a built-in prior that has a support that does not include non-negative values.  poisson or exponential are obvious possibilities.  Please make your example reproducible.

I want to have default priors for median and weight. I just want to have specific priors for length. If I use negative_length wouldn't the intepretation change? I was thinking to add sth like control.fixed = list(
mean = list(length = -1000),
prec = list(length = 1)) but I am not sure if it is correct.
